# Matlab Outlook COM interface: lookup contact

Tags: matlab, outlook, com

I'd like to look up a contact, especially the username, by outlook COM (or any other means feasible/possible).

This is what I started with, and I'm a bit lost since COM functions seem not to be documented by MathWorks directly.

```
%get activeX element
outlook=actxserver('outlook.Application'); 
%get default folder
defaultFolder=outlook.GetNamespace('mapi').GetDefaultFolder('olFolderInbox');
```

and a ref in c++: [Search Outlook Contact using COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811974/search-outlook-contact-using-com).

How do I get to a cell-array of contacts/emails?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "look up a contact"? Show the Outlook address book?

Comment: yes, something like: find a contact name, display email address. Basically once the whole addressbook is accessible via some variable/cell array(?) this should be easy to do

Comment: I still do not quite understand - do you want to display the address book to the end user and have him/her select an entry? Or, given a name, resolve that name to an address entry so that you can read its email address etc.?

Comment: So 1) I would like all of the addressbook of the current outlook user in one variable. The addressbook usally includes fields like 'First Name', 'Name', 'Emailaddress' etc. 2) I want to query this addressbook within matlab to automate writing emails / resolve email names to usernames

Comment: "all of the addressbook... in one variable" There are address books providers that can include 10s of thousands, or even millions of entries.

Comment: My addressbook may not have 10s of thousands entries. But even then, using tall arrays, it could be processed with Matlab...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168864/discussion-between-user2305193-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Comment: Once again, unless you need *all* of the address entries, retrieving them all is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolve a name, call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` (returns `Recipient` object). Call `Recipient.Resolve` before accessing its properties such as Recipient.Name.

If you are creating messages, you can resolve recipients using `MailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll`.

In VB:

```
set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
ns.Logon
set recip = ns.CreateRecipient("Joe The User")
if recip.Resolve Then
  MsgBox recip.Address
End If
```

Comment: it's not clear to me how to call `Namespace.CreateRecipient`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to achieve this in Matlab - it _is_ in the title and implied in the question

Comment: The programing language wouldn't matter - Outlook Object Model does not know or care who is calling it.

Comment: I care - and I need it to be matlab code, otherwise I do not understand how to implement it into a matlab script. It's fine, this question should be closed I guess.